# Double Integral: finding the area using a parametric equation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$
r = \cos (3\theta)
$$
I need to find the area of one loop of the rose made by this function. I know that the bound for $\theta$ is $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ for one of the loops. Although I don't know how to set up my $r$ values. I believe that the interior function would simply be $1$ since we're just trying to find the area. Can you help me set up this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, since you are trying to find the area, the integral can simply be weighted by 1. In polar coordinates, the area of the entire 3-petal graph is given by
$$A=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2}r(\theta)^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(3\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
and so the area of a single petal is $\pi/12.$

Here is a Mathematica plot of the function:

```
PolarPlot[Cos[3 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are integrating over a range where $r$ is negative (in the beginning and the end). Thus you actually measure all three loops. The range where $r$ is nonnegative is actually only $[-\pi/6,\pi/6]$. Using that would divide your result by $3$, as it should be.

Comment: Another way to see this: Your parametric plot has the same $\theta$ range as the integral, and the plot covers all three loops.

Comment: And a plausibility check: $\pi/4$ is a quarter of the area enclosed by the bounding circle. Obviously, one loop alone cannot yield that much.

Comment: @ccorn: Whoops, I thought the question was asking for the total area (I missed the "one loop" part of the question). Fixing it.